# множественное число сущ

Tags: орфография

как вы определяете окончание сущ. множ. числа.
Профессор-профессора, доктор-доктора, тополь-тополя, но: договор-договоры ну и т.д.
Вроде бы определенного правила нет и нужно запоминать это все.
 Может знает секрет, как сразу понять какое окончание?

Comment: Отвечали на эти вопросы уже миллион раз. Если не знаете, смотрите в словари.

Answer (score 1):

1) Варианты окончаний обычно имеют **сущ. м.р. 2-го скл.**, основным окончанием для них является **Ы/И,** но встречается и вариантное окончание **А/Я**.

2) Если слово имеет один вариант произношения (дом - дома), то такие слова нас не интересуют, даже если они имеют вариантное окончание А/Я.Под контролем следует держать существительные, **которые могут иметь оба окончания**, при этом эти окончания могут различаться **по смыслу и стилю**.

3) Наибольшую трудность представляют многосложные сущ. м.р., у которых **ударение падает на второй от конца слог,** так как именно они могут иметь два вида окончаний, причем ударное окончание А/Я чаще является разговорным, а окончание Ы/И относится к нейтральному стилю.

4) Но это основная статистика, так как есть **слова-исключения, их надо запомнить:**

А) только вариантное окончание А (слова этой группы рекомендуется запомнить): профессорА, директорА, докторА, шулерА

Б)  только основное окончание Ы: ректоры, лекторы, бухгалтеры, диспетчеры, снайперы, редукторы, центнеры;

В) допускаются оба варианта: инспекторы и инспекторА, теноры и тенорА, джемперы и джемперА, свитеры и свитерА (окончание Ы относится к нейтральному стилю, а окончание А – к разговорному стилю).

Примечание. **Существительное договОр** (с ударением на последнем слоге) также имеет также имеет одну форму договОры с окончанием Ы, но существует разговорная форма дОговор – договорА с окончанием А из другой акцентной группы.